# Какие языки программирования используют для разработки фронт-энда?

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

Интересуют актуальные и востребованные языки и технологии.

Comment: вопрос звучит как на экзамене)

Comment: Просто стало интересно, что ещё помимо js используется :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- JavaScript, JScript
- ActionScript (Flash)
- C# (Silverlight)
- Java (JavaFX)

Comment: ++

Comment: Забыли Java (GWT)

Comment: GWT просто генерирует JS. Так что мне кажется он не в счет.

Comment: А еще html5 :)

Answer (score 1):

Java (апплеты) - редко, впрочем.
(забавно, а ведь когда-то о Java говорили "вы не подумайте, это не только апплеты").

Answer (score 1):

F#. Удивил? Использую [вот это](http://www.websharper.com). Чертовски доволен что не надо писать руками ненавистный javascript.

Comment: Ну как бы можно и GWT в подобную категорию отнести, я прав?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript.

**UPD0**: Ну может [CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script) в случае Ruby on Rails.

А разве есть что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0):

[Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). Я там не особо понял где бэк-энд, где фронт-энд, но как любителя плюсов этот фрэймворк впечатлил просто до визга =)
 ***P.S.** Может и не совсем в тему ответил, но все же считаю нужным поделиться с теми кто не знал что есть и такая возможность.*